Get best possible combination
I have a problem where multiple products are packed in different quantities in different boxes. Each box is identified by its specific id.
For example the order is 3 qty of Product A, 6 quantity of Product B and 15 quantity of Product C. There are 5 boxes available.
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    order_id INT,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product, quantity) VALUES
(101, 'Product A', 3),
(101, 'Product B', 6),
(101, 'Product C', 15);


CREATE TABLE Boxes (
box_id INT,
product VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO Boxes (box_id, product, quantity) VALUES
(1, 'Product A', 2), (1, 'Product B', 3), (1, 'Product C', 4),
(2, 'Product A', 2), (2, 'Product B', 6), (2, 'Product C', 1),
(3, 'Product A', 2), (3, 'Product B', 3), (3, 'Product C', 4),
(4, 'Product A', 0), (4, 'Product B', 0), (4, 'Product C', 9),
(5, 'Product A', 0), (5, 'Product B', 3), (5, 'Product C', 6);

Based on above, the best result would be to select box 1, 3 and 4 as we can complete the order by opening just 3 boxes.
I have tried this approach but it is not workable if I have more than 500 products.
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE FulfillOrderComplex
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RemainingA INT, @RemainingB INT, @RemainingC INT;
    SET @RemainingA = 3; -- Example order requirements
    SET @RemainingB = 6;
    SET @RemainingC = 15;

    -- Temporary table to track box selections
    CREATE TABLE #SelectedBoxes (box_id INT);

    -- Logic to select boxes
    WHILE (@RemainingA > 0 OR @RemainingB > 0 OR @RemainingC > 0)
    BEGIN
        -- Find the box that maximizes the reduction of remaining quantities
        DECLARE @BestBox INT;
        SELECT TOP 1 @BestBox = box_id FROM Boxes
        WHERE (quantity >= @RemainingA AND product = 'Product A') OR
              (quantity >= @RemainingB AND product = 'Product B') OR
              (quantity >= @RemainingC AND product = 'Product C')
        ORDER BY (CASE WHEN product = 'Product A' THEN @RemainingA - quantity
                       WHEN product = 'Product B' THEN @RemainingB - quantity
                       WHEN product = 'Product C' THEN @RemainingC - quantity END);

        -- Update remaining requirements
        UPDATE @RemainingA, @RemainingB, @RemainingC based on @BestBox contents;

        -- Add @BestBox to selected boxes
        INSERT INTO #SelectedBoxes VALUES (@BestBox);

        -- Avoid selecting the same box again
        DELETE FROM Boxes WHERE box_id = @BestBox;
    END

    -- Return the selected boxes
    SELECT box_id FROM #SelectedBoxes;
END;

Can someone help me to write an SQL query which give me IDs of boxes to open to fulfill the order while making sure that minimum number boxes are opened irrespective of how many products does the order contains.

What happens above 500 products?

When you have an algorithm to implement, it's best to do it using a programming language. SQL is not a programming language.

What I mean was, I want to make is product independent. Irrespective of how many products and their respective quantities are there, the query should return the result. What I believe is that I might need to use recursive function here.

I cannot use programming language here. May be I can get the data in Excel and do something from there.

I was working on the logic that a) get the require quantity of products in a temp table. b) get the available quantity of boxes and their respective product quantities in a secondary temp table. c) identify which box is the most suited one and put that box in the selected temp table d) remove selected box from available quantity temp table e) update required quantity temp table to reduce the required quantity based on selected box f) run the process again for remaining required quantity and updated available stock until the whole order is completed

One way is to break the problem into smaller problems, so you can write a SQL function and use a loop inside that function to score your boxes in each iteration based on the orders that have not yet been answered. and choose the box with the highest score among them

Your logic in the above comment seems ok? What's not working about it?

the problem you describe is called knapp sac problem and it's NP complete, so you have to usually use brute force to try different combinations. It quickly becomes very slow with more items as well. There have been a couple of answers on how to do it, but your case have a bit more complex requirements that a box contains multiple products, making it even more complicated

One way to solve it is to generate all combination of boxes that fulfill the sum of all orders at hand, and then see which combination generates the best outcome

@DaleK I am confused on point c. How to identify which one is the most suited box among the available boxes.

You are looking for the best branch(es) in a tree of possibilities: an algorithm looking for the best node at each step does not guarantee to find the best branch(es): a "not that good" node may hide a following "very good branch"...
Generating the combinaisons of the boxes will be the most costly: you have to compare among all the C(n,p) covering the order which tuple(s) gives the best solution, and most efficient algorithm uses power of 2 to implement it, which limit the # of boxes to the greatest power of 2 your DB can handle, unless going to other algo, # of products is less a problem.
To get the list of covering sets of boxes:
(CTE1) first calculate the quantity of each (order, product) you have in the boxes,
(CTE2) keep only the orders that can be satisfied, report the others
(CTE3) calculate the power of 2 of the row number for each box
(CTE4) calculate the C(n,p) tuples among the boxes using the 2^rownum algo
(CTE5) joining each tuple member to the box it represents, check the order (among the ones from CTE2) is satisfied, return the corresponding tuples
Solution: calculate according to your criteria the "quality" of each returned tuple
Example result from CTE5 where the quality will be the smallest # of boxes:
1,3,4       3   101 1
1,2,3,5     4   101 2
1,2,4,5     4   101 2
1,3,4,5     4   101 2
2,3,4,5     4   101 2
1,2,3,4     4   101 2
1,2,3,4,5   5   101 3

The latest column being the dense rank on the ascending cardinality (col 2) of the tuple.
While an algorithm based on the "best" node (e.g. "best" according to the quantity of products used...) may give as solution: 4,2,5,1.
